# "Expanding his chest went out of the room."

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context, style

Source: Anna Karenina

> - For a few seconds Oblonsky stood alone; then he wiped his eyes, sighed, and ***expanding*** his chest ***went*** ***out*** of the room.

Why isn't this sentence in this way: wiped his eyes, sighed, ***expanded*** his chest, ***and*** went out of the room.

Comment: It is the act-in-progress that is important emotionally here, not the achieved stated of expandedness. He doesn't leave the room holding his breath. :)  We could say alternatively "and taking a deep breath...". Contrast that with:  *He pulled his goggles over his eyes, grabbed his speargun, **took** a deep breath, and dived into the sea.*

Answer (score 3):

"Anna Karenina" is a Russian novel, translated to English.  "Expanding his chest" might be the best translation of a Russian idiom, but it's not idiomatic in English.

We might say someone *"puffed out his chest"* to indicate confidence or braggadocio, but in this case the translator should have substituted a more appropriate English idiom like "he gathered himself together" or "he took a few deep breaths", to show he's trying to "regain his composure".

In any case, "expanding his chest" is a [participle phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm) that acts as an adjective (not a verb) which modifies the pronoun "he".  Other examples:

> *Gathering his strength*, he pushed the heavy rock out of the way.
>
> *Drying his eyes*, he resolved never to fall in love again.
>
> *Searching his pockets*, he found a few dollars for bus fare.

Comment: The idiomatic phrase that comes to mind for this is *taking a deep breath, he...* It might be worth mentioning that it's phrased as a participle phrase rather than added to the string of past-tense verbs to indicate that, while the wiping of eyes and sighing all happened while he was still in the room, the chest-expanding happened as he was leaving the room (or maybe as he took his first step towards the door).

Comment: You mean that we can put it in this way: expanding his chest, he went out of the room, or in this way: he, expanding his chest, went out of the room. But expanding, in this sentence, seems to me that is a gerund not an adjective.

Comment: @BavyanYaldo yes, you can put the pronoun first, but it's doesn't sound as good.  And yes, a participle phrase *looks* a lot like a gerund phrase, but they act differently.  "*Expanding his chest* was painful with his cracked ribs"  has a gerund phrase, because it acts like a noun.